# FB Messenger Chat Heads not opening when React Native app is in foreground

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I have a React Native app running on the foreground and I am unable to click to open the Facebook Messenger chat head bubble. It just flashes when it is pressed on, but does not open the chat overlay.

I can't find anything related to this.

Is there any way to fix this? Not sure if its an Android Studio configuration that needs to be added?

EDIT: Just to add, I'm using `react-native-navigation` by Wix, https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation, not sure if that is the one causing this.

Comment: Please show me the code that is in question.